# Stuck when tackling the computation of $\Phi_n(\zeta_8)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, cyclotomic-polynomials

My current way of calculation of $\Phi_n(\zeta_8)$ where $\Phi_n(x)$ is the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial and $\zeta_8=\cos(\frac{2\pi}{8})+i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{8})$ leave me now stuck at the problem of calculating $$\prod_{d|n}\sin(\frac{d2\pi}{16})^{\mu(\frac{n}{d})}$$ the product running over all integer divisors 0f $n$. $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function.

My tests with WolframAlpha Online resulted for e.g. prime $n$ and $n$ squarefree with maximally $2$ prime divisors the for me astonishing results of $\pm 1$,$\pm \cot(\frac{\pi}{8})$,$\pm \cot^2(\frac{\pi}{8})$,$\pm \tan(\frac{\pi}{8})$,$\pm \tan^2(\frac{\pi}{8})$ so far.

I see no way how I could find a closed form for the product which the CAS calculations lead me to conjecture to exist.

Comment: Ough. Sorry for the typos. I will correct them.

Comment: It's no wonder that only a handful of possible values came up, since you only looked at primes and nonsquare semiprimes - cyclotomic polynomials are very sensitive to factorization. Indeed it's fairly easy to give a closed form for those two types of numbers. But as the complexity of $n$'s prime factorization increases, the situation becomes more complicated. Nor is it too surprising the values you did get had nice compact forms, since they are small sums of small roots of unity; bigger numbers might yield a greater variety of values which are less compact and occur with less predictability .

Comment: I recommend seeing what happens when you try a broader range of $n$s. Also, could you state in explicit terms exactly what your conjecture is? You could also show more work in order to save readers the time of reproducing what results you do have. I personally haven't checked your values.

Comment: I now made calculations of the product until $n=40$ omitting the complicated case of $n\equiv0\mod4$ and zero divisions if $n\equiv0\mod16$. Things seem not becoming very complicated. As results I get $\pm 1$ and $\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$ or its square or the inverse of it and its square. This set of results I also get when calculating from $n=100$ to $n=110$ which I think is surprising. Alas I dont even see how "it's fairly easy to give a closed form for those two types of numbers" (citation from above).

Comment: Same results in the range of $n=300$ to $n=340$.

Comment: Interesting. At the moment I can't see any reason to expect $\{\Phi_n(\zeta):n\in\Bbb N\}$ to be finite (which is what I assume your conjecture is) but I will think about it further.

Comment: Hm, I suppose you are right. Note that the calculation of $\Phi_n(\zeta_8)$ is another story. I also suppose that there is to apply an exponentiation with some expression of the Euler $\phi$-function. But I am interested/puzzled in the product of $\sin$-values : otherwise I am stuck with the further calculation of $\Phi_n(\zeta_8)$.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the first counterexample to your conjecture (which, as I understood it, was basically that $|\Phi_n(e^{2\pi i/8})|=\tan(\frac{\pi}{8})^e$ with $|e|\le2$) occurs at $n=3\cdot5\cdot11=156$, where instead the exponent is $-4$. My answer does prove that the absolute value, when it isn't busy being $1$, is always of the form $\tan(\pi/8)^{\pm2^k}$ for some $k\ge0$ though. The exact value involves signs that depend sensitively on the factorization of $n$, although not as much as I imagined it might. So this is a mean between our two predictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a classic and elementary fact that since $x^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(x)$, by applying $\log$s to both sides followed by Mobius inversion and then exponentiating back we must have

$$\Phi_n(x)=\prod_{d\mid n}(x^d-1)^{\mu(n/d)}.$$

This is mentioned in almost any source that covers cyclotomic polynomials. Furthermore,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \displaystyle \prod_{d\mid n}(x^d-1)^{\mu(n/d)} & \displaystyle =\prod_{d\mid n}x^{d\mu(n/d)/2}(x^{d/2}-x^{-d/2})^{\mu(n/d)} \\ & \displaystyle =x^{\large\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum\limits_{d\mid n}d\mu(n/d)\right]}\prod_{d\mid n}(x^{d/2}-x^{-d/2})^{\mu(n/d)}. \end{array}$$

Here is a well-known technique utilized in the number theory of arithmetic functions:  since $\sum_{d\mid n}d\mu(n/d)$ is a convolution of [multiplicative functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) it is itself multiplicative, hence equals

$$\prod_{p^e\|n}\left(\sum_{r=0}^e p^r\mu(p^e/p^r)\right)=\prod_{p^e\|n}(p^e-p^{e-1})= \varphi(n).$$

The notation $p^e\|n$ when $p$ is a prime means that $p^e\mid n$ but $p^{e+1}\nmid n$, or in other words that $p^e$ is the precise power of $p$ present in $n$'s prime factorization. Thus we have

$$\Phi_n(x)=x^{\varphi(n)/2}\prod_{d\mid n}(x^{d/2}-x^{-d/2})^{\mu(n/d)}.$$

If $x=e^{2\pi i\frac{k}{m}}$ then $x^{d/2}-x^{-d/2}=2i\sin(\pi\frac{kd}{m})$ by [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula#Relationship_to_trigonometry), and so by factoring out all of the terms $(2i)^{\mu(n/d)}$ and then using the fact $\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n/d)=0$ if $n>1$ we get

$$\Phi_n(e^{2\pi i\frac{k}{m}})=e^{\pi i\frac{\varphi(n)k}{m}}\prod_{d\mid n}\sin\left(\pi\frac{kd}{m}\right)^{\mu(n/d)}.$$

Now let's specialize to the case $k/m=1/8$ and $n$ odd. It is geometrically "obvious" that

$$\begin{array}{|c|rrrrrrrr|}\hline d\bmod 16 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 9 & 11 & 13 & 15 \\ \hline
\sin(\pi\frac{d}{8}) & s & c & c & s & -s & -c & -c & -s \\ \hline \end{array} $$

where $s=\sin(\frac{\pi}{8})~\left(=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}\,\right)$ and $c=\cos(\frac{\pi}{8})~\left(=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}\,\right)$. Therefore

$$\Phi_n(e^{2\pi i/8})=e^{i\pi \varphi(n)/8}(-1)^{v_{9,11,13,15}(n)}\sin(\frac{\pi}{8})^{v_{1,7,9,15}(n)}\cos(\frac{\pi}{8})^{v_{3,5,11,13}(n)} \tag{1}$$

using the ad hoc functions $v_S(n)=\sum_{d\mid n,d\in S\bmod16}\mu(n/d)$. Let's simply abbreviate this

$$\Phi_n(e^{2\pi i/8})=e^{i\pi\varphi(n)/8}(-1)^{\gamma(n)}\sin(\frac{\pi}{8})^{\alpha(n)}\cos(\frac{\pi}{8})^{\beta(n)}.$$

The fact $\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n/d)=0$ (given $n>1$) tells us $\alpha(n)+\beta(n)=0$. Simplifying we get

$$\Phi_n(e^{2\pi i/8})=e^{i\pi\varphi(n)/8}(-1)^{\gamma(n)}\tan(\frac{\pi}{8})^{\alpha(n)}. $$

Notice something special: the residues $\overline{1},\overline{7},\overline{9},\overline{15}$ form an index two subgroup of $U(16)$, so they are the kernel of some homomorphism $\theta:U(16)\to\{\pm1\}$. Indeed we have

$$\theta(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x^2\equiv1 \mod{16} \\ -1 & x^2\not\equiv 1\mod{16}.\end{cases} \tag{2}$$

Therefore with some trickery we can rewrite $\alpha(n)$ via

$$\alpha(n)=\frac{\alpha(n)-\beta(n)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n/d)\theta(\overline{d})=\frac{1}{2}\prod_{p^e\|n}\left(\sum_{r=0}^e\mu(p^e/p^r)\theta(\overline{p})^r\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\prod_{p^e\|n}\left(\theta(\overline{p})^e-\theta(\overline{p})^{e-1}\right)=\frac{\theta(\overline{n})}{2}\prod_{p\mid n}(1-\theta(\overline{p})) $$

$$\alpha(n)=\begin{cases}\theta(\overline{n})2^{\omega(n)-1} & {\rm if}~p^2\not\equiv1\bmod16~{\rm for~each~prime~}p\mid n \\ 0 & {\rm if}~p^2\equiv1\bmod16~{\rm for~any~~prime~}p\mid n. \end{cases} \tag{3}$$

The function $\omega(n)$ counts the number of prime factors of $n$. And so we conclude

**Theorem**. $\Phi_n(e^{2\pi i/8})=e^{i\pi\varphi(n)/8}(-1)^{\gamma(n)}\tan(\frac{\pi}{8})^{\alpha(n)}$ where $\alpha,\gamma$ are defined in $(1),(2),(3)$, for any odd integer $n>1$.

In particular, the first $n$ for which the product of sines fails to have absolute value $\tan(\frac{\pi}{8})^e$ for an exponent $|e|\le2$ occurs at $n=3\cdot5\cdot11=165$, where $|\Phi_{165}(e^{2\pi i/8})|=\tan(\frac{\pi}{8})^{-4}$.

Comment: Great analysis on how the $\tan(\frac{\pi}{8})$ is dependent on the prime factorization of $n$ odd.  What I also thought about is a generalization to $\Phi_n(\zeta_{2^r})$ as one has the nice sequence of $1$,$-1$,$i$,$\zeta_8$, etc. for $r=0,1,2,3,\cdots$. But I this may be overwhelmingly difficult to formulate for general $r$.

Comment: Maybe the Formula (**) of Emil Jerabek for the case $r=2$ ( i.e $\Phi_n(i)$ ) given here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180434/looking-for-ways-how-to-calculate-phi-ni is interesting if not yet seen/known.

Answer (score 0):

I think I derived a proof of the following formula for $n>1$. I did also a CAS test run for $n=1$ to $n=262$ confirming the formula. $$\Phi_n(\zeta_8)=\zeta_{16}^{\phi(n)}\prod_{d|n}\sin(d\frac{2\pi}{16})^{\mu(\frac{n}{d})}$$

Comment: This doesn't say anything you didn't already say in the question...